# My Pythonic take on Psexec

Tags: python, python-2.x, shell

I've created a little program that basically does the same thing as [psexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx). It will connect to a host via computer name, or IP address, run the given command, and log the output into a file (little extra for myself). I would like some critique on what I've done, what can I do better, what did I do well, etc.. Some key points I would like to look at are (of course critique everything):

1. Logging to a file, is there better ways to do so?
2. Connecting and executing a shell command quicker

```
import wmi
import sys
import socket
import subprocess
import logging
import getpass
import os
import time
from colorlog import ColoredFormatter


log_level = logging.INFO
logger_format = "[%(log_color)s%(asctime)s %(levelname)s%(reset)s] %(log_color)s%(message)s%(reset)s"
logging.root.setLevel(log_level)
formatter = ColoredFormatter(logger_format, datefmt="%I:%M:%S")
stream = logging.StreamHandler()
stream.setLevel(log_level)
stream.setFormatter(formatter)
LOGGER = logging.getLogger('pyshellConfig')
LOGGER.setLevel(log_level)
LOGGER.addHandler(stream)


def create_log(dest_ip, host_ip, command, data):
    """
    :param dest_ip: Destination IP address
    :param host_ip: IP address of where the command was run
    :param command: Command that was run
    :param data: Output of the command

    Write the output of the run command to a log file for further analysis
    """
    log_path = "C:\\Users\\{}\\AppData\\pyshell".format(getpass.getuser())
    if not os.path.isdir(log_path):
        os.mkdir(log_path)

    with open("{}\\{}_LOG.LOG".format(log_path, __file__), "a+") as log:
        log.write("![{}][LOG FROM:{} TO:{}]COMMAND RUN: {} OUTPUT:{}\n".format(time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y::%H:%M:%S"),
                                                                               host_ip, dest_ip,
                                                                               command, data))


def connect(hostname, command=None):
    """ 
    :param hostname: Computer name or IP address
    :param command: Shell command to be run on the host

    Connect to the host and run a shell command on their system
    """
    LOGGER.info("Attempting to connect to host: '{}'".format(hostname))
    try:
        connection = wmi.WMI(hostname)  # Attempt to connect to the hostname
        if connection:
            LOGGER.info("Connected successfully, running command: '{}'".format(' '.join(command)))
            call = subprocess.Popen(command,
                                    shell=False,
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            output = call.communicate("Running remote command...")  # Start running the command and save output to variable
            create_log(socket.gethostbyname(hostname), socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()),
                       command, output)
            LOGGER.info("Command completed successfully.")
    except Exception, e:  # I don't think there's really anyway of getting the exact error from the shell
        error_message = "Failed to connect due to %s. " % e
        error_message += "\nThis could mean that '%s' is not the correct " % hostname
        error_message += "computer name, or that the host has refused it. "
        error_message += "You can try to connect via IP address, if the "
        error_message += "user is able to get it."
        LOGGER.fatal(error_message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    help_page = """python shell.py [HOST] [COMMAND]"""
    error_message = ""

    try:
        if not sys.argv[1::]:  # User ARGV for the arguments to more match Psexec
            error_message += "You did not supply a hostname to run against\n{}".format(help_page)
            LOGGER.fatal(error_message)
            exit(1)
        elif not sys.argv[2::]:
            error_message += "You did not supply a command to run\n{}".format(help_page)
            LOGGER.fatal(error_message)
            exit(1)

        connect(sys.argv[1].upper(), command=sys.argv[2::])
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Excellent job with your first question - this is *exactly* what this site is for! I hope you get great reviews! =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep your imports grouped. From PEP 8.

[Imports should be grouped in the following order](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

> 1. standard library imports
> 2. related third party imports
> 3. local application/library specific imports

---

Follow Python's [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) principle instead of checking if something exists. Plus when it comes to folder creation it will also help you avoid race-condition.

```
import errno

try:
    os.mkdir(log_path)
except Exception as e:
    if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        # If error is something other than file
        # path already exists then handle it here.
        pass
```

---

Note my use of `except Exception as e` here instead of `except Exception, e`. The latter syntax is deprecated and has been removed in Python 3. Hence go for `as` based format.

---

Your try-except block is huge. Cover minimum statements at once, it will help you in narrowing down the actual problem easily and you will be able to show a much better error message to user. Have multiple try-excepts as long as they don't make the code too unreadable.

---

Instead of dealing with `sys.argv` you could use the [arsparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) module to handle command line args in much better way.

---

`error_message = ""` statement is not required. You can simply define it wherever you need it instead of defining a default value.

---

`[1::]` and `[2::]` can be simply written as `[1:]` and `[2:]` respectively.

---

The `IndexError` at the end is redundant because you're already checking for `if not [1::]` earlier and exiting the script right away, hence you would never hit that exception. Note that slicing never raises `IndexError`.

---

`call.communicate("Running remote command...")` returns both STDOUT and STDIN. You can consider using them separately.

Plus you could also check the status code by doing `call.returncode`. A non-zero exit code means an error.

---

`log_path = "C:\\Users\\{}\\AppData\\pyshell".format(getpass.getuser())`

A hard-coded path is not a good idea. Perhaps ask the user for a path?

You can also get path to user's home directory using [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser).

`log_path = r"{home}\AppData\pyshell".format(home=os.path.expanduser('~'))`

Note that I also added `r""` so that we can simply use a single backslash.

Comment: I can't seem to get a valid reference for `e.errno`, is this specific to python 3.x?

Comment: @User9123 The error code is defined here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html#errno.EEXIST. I am not sure if they're available in Windows.